# Where is the fallacy in the argument using Prime Number Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am reading about Prime Number Theorem from book by Ingham. As as application of PNT I found the following theorem:
[image]

Now my doubt is at the step $\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)}\rightarrow 1$, we can say $\log(y)\rightarrow\log(x)$ and if I apply antilog I get $y\rightarrow x$ which is not true by PNT.

So where is the fallacy in my argument?

I think it is because we are neglecting $\log\log x$ term, but I am not sure and I am unable to find a suitable argument.

Also we are applying $\log$ on PNT even though it is kind of limit, So why cant we apply antilog. Are there any conditions to apply some function for these kind of cases?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The arrow "$\to$" in $\frac{\log y}{\log x} \to 1$ is not the same as an equality sign ($=$). It means (see the "when $x \to \infty$" a couple of lines above) that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log y}{\log x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log \pi(x)}{\log x} = 1.$$

You *cannot* conclude from this that $\log y \to \log x$, simply because that statement isn't very meaningful. (E.g. if you use it to mean that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \log y = \log x$, then this is nonsensical as $x$ is a varying (increasing) variable on the left-hand-side of the equation, and what value does it take on the right-hand-side?)

As an example, consider the statement that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n} = 1.$$ This is a true statement, but you cannot use $\frac{n+1}{n} \to 1$ to conclude that $n+1 \to n$, nor can you then subtract $n$ from both sides to say that $1 \to 0$.

---

**Edit**: I see that there is some scope for confusion, because in the proof quoted in the question, they *do seem* to perform operations that *look like* they're taking logs on both sides of "$\to$" and treating it like an equality sign, etc. But this is not actually what they're doing, so let's rewrite the proof without the "$\to$" symbol to be clear. With $y = \pi(x)$, we have, by the Prime Number Theorem, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{y \log x}{x} = 1.$$ 
Now, we can "take logarithms" by using the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \log g(x) = \log \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ at good places, which is basically a consequence of the fact that $\log$ is a continuous function: see [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Chain_rule). So we get 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \log \frac{y \log x}{x} = \log 1 = 0.$$ 
This is the same as 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\log y + \log \log x - \log x) = 0$$
Dividing throughout by $\log x$ (product rule), we get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{\log y}{\log x} + \frac{\log \log x}{\log x} - \frac{\log x}{\log x}) = 0$$
Now using the facts $\frac{\log x}{\log x} = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log \log x}{\log x} = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}(a(x) + b(x)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} a(x) + \lim_{x\to\infty} b(x)$ when all exist ("sum rule"), this becomes
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log y}{\log x} = 1$$
Finally, we have 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{y\log y}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{y\log x}{x}\frac{\log y}{\log x}) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{y\log x}{x} \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log y}{\log x} = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$$
as both limits exist; this is the "product rule" for limits again.

---

Conclusion: By default, you cannot freely perform operations on limits and expect them to work out. There are certain things you can do, but this must be justified. (BTW, taking antilog of both sides is something you *can* do: e.g. from $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log y}{\log x} = 1$, you *can* conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\frac{\log y}{\log x}} = e$. It's just that the expression $\log y \to \log x$ is meaningless.)

So rather than asking why we can't do certain things, the right question is to ask why we can do the operations we do, and examine them closely.

Comment: I meant $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}$ when i written as $x\rightarrow y$.\\

So can explain is there a way to know when we can do a certain operation or not. We know that the example given by you is right.\\

But you see in the proof given in the book they took log on bothsides. I understand that When i apply antilog i am getting absurd answer and so it shouldn't be done. But I am asking WHY can't we do?

Comment: @PhaniRaj: I've updated my answer. In short, you should ask "why can we do", not "why can't we do". :-) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties which mentions sums, differences, products, quotients, and the chain rule. There are a few operations you can do, and in general both log and antilog are things you can do (except taking log near 0, etc). Your absurd result comes not from applying antilog (which would be fine) but from using $\frac{\log y}{\log x} \to 1$ to generate the meaningless statement $\log y \to \log x$.

Comment: 'you should ask "why can we do", not "why can't we do"' < I completely agree with this. You can't do it simply because it's false. It turns true statements into false statements. Multiplying both sides of an *equality* by a function tends to turn true statements into true statements, but not both sides of a $\to$ statement. (Similarly, why is tan(x+y) not equal to tan(x) + tan(y)? Well, for the same reason that tan(x+y) isn't equal to x^2 + exp(y). *It just isn't.*) I know this may not be a satisfying answer, though.

Comment: @PhaniRaj: Do leave a comment if something's still unclear. Basically $\log y\to\log x$ doesn't mean anything as the RHS of a limit must be some expression that does not depend on the varying quantity (here, $x$) wrt which you're taking the limit. Also, if you try something involving the expression $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log y}{\log x}\lim_{x\to\infty}\log x$ then it's invalid as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log x$ does not exist (is infinite). So that's one thing you can't do: can't multiply both sides by an infinite limit. (This is basically covered in the limit properties link above.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example: $${\log(1000x)\over\log x}\to1$$ but if you try your antilog technique you get $${1000x\over x}\to1$$ which is nonsense. Think about what happens in this simple example and you may be able to work out what the difficulty is.

Comment: Note that the antilog of $\frac{\log(1000x)}{\log x}$ is actually $e^{\frac{\log(1000x)}{\log x}}$, and that of $1$ is $e$ (assuming natural logs), and $e^{\frac{\log(1000x)}{\log x}} \to e$ is actually correct. I interpreted the OP as "correctly" taking antilog on the meaningless expression $\log y \to \log x$.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, yes, but going from $a/b$ to $a\to b$ to $e^a\to e^b$ is the same error as going from $a/b$ to $e^a/e^b$.

Comment: Good point, I agree. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is where [little $o$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) and [big $O$ notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) can clarify things greatly.  You have that $$\log y=(1+o(1))\log x.$$  Exponentiating, this implies that $$y=x^{1+o(1)}.$$  The important thing is that the function $x^{1+o(1)}$ does not necessarily converge to $1$ - in fact it can be quite large.  Let $f(x)=\frac{K\log \log x}{ \log x}$ is $o(1)$, and in this case $$x^{f(x)}=\exp\left(\frac{K\log \log x}{ \log x}\cdot \log x\right)$$ $$=(\log x)^K.$$

Comment: Converge to $x$, you mean, not to 1.